# Mac is confused about the display

Tags: macos, display

I have `macOS 10.15.7` on a `MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)`.

I have an external `GIGABYTE M27Q` monitor that has been working just fine with resolution `2560x1440` and *still* works with a linux laptop just fine.

Yesterday I used the MacBook with a different monitor (Dell u3415w) and now the MacBook thinks that the GIGABYTE is DELL, i.e., the `Display Preferences` identifies it as a DELL and uses `3440x1440` resolution (noticeably wrong aspect ratio).

The monitor is connected via HDML-to-USB-C cable.

### Diagnostics:

`Apple  Menu ---> About This Mac ---> Displays` shows

- `Built-in Display` (`3072x1920` --- *correct*) and
- `DELL U3415W Display` (`3440x1440` --- *incorrect*)

both using `AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB graphics`.

When the external display is unplugged, `Built-in Display` uses `Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB graphics`.

### Tried:

- Un-plugging and re-plugging the cables and power-cycling the monitor.
- Sleeping and waking up the laptop.
- <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Detect Displays</kbd> in display settings

#### workaround

<kbd>option</kbd> + `Resolution: Scaled` in the `Display Preferences` shows **more** options, including the correct option `2560x1440`. Thus now the display shows correct size and aspect ratio, but is *named* incorrectly.

## How do I make Mac recognize the display correctly?

Answer (score 2):

### How to choose screen resolutions within System Preferences

Choose Apple menu   > **System Preferences…** > **Display** > **Resolution**. Then hold <kbd>⌥</kbd> [*Option Key*] while clicking at **Scaled**. Without holding <kbd>⌥</kbd> you can just change the size of text and objects on your screen; but clicking **Scaled** while holding the <kbd>⌥</kbd> [*Option Key*] you can switch between screen resolutions.

For better understanding see both variants in the screenshots:

[image: Example by selecting 'Scaled' without pressed ⌥-Key]

[image: Example by selecting 'Scaled' with pressed ⌥-Key]

#### Proper detection of the external display

Side note: Maybe it could be interesting which display has been recognised by macOS. Just choose Apple menu   > About This Mac > Displays. It should show something like…
**Integrated Retina-Display**
16-Inch (3072 x 1920)

…for the internal display.

How about the external display? Does macOS recognise the attached Gigabyte M27Q properly?

### Addendum to my previous suggestion in order to fix the primary problem

As **Display profiles** are stored under **Color** it was not obvious that this might be the profile you just have to delete it.

I do not know if it works, but it's worth a try:

[image]